# WSO2 EI: Expired certificate error when connecting from embedded MI to EI analytics server

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

Downloaded *wso2ei-analytics-7.1.0* and started the server and dashboard. Then I enabled statistics for the APIs and endpoints and added the following config into the embedded MI of the Integration studio:

```
[mediation]
flow.statistics.enable=true
stat.tracer.collect_payloads=true
stat.tracer.collect_mediation_properties=true
flow.statistics.capture_all=true
```

When starting the embedded MI I get the following error saying some certificate has expired:

```
[2022-06-23 09:47:40,001] ERROR {DataEndpointConnectionWorker} - Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712. org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712.
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:145)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Error while trying to login to the data receiver.
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:54)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:139)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:161)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:65)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.send_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:95)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:47)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1339)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1214)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1157)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1309)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:814)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1184)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:159)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:275)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1323)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:237)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:145)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:84)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:364)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Tue Jan 25 13:00:43 IST 2022
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:277)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:675)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyValidity(BasicChecker.java:190)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:144)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
```

I am assuming the MI trust store does not have the correct certificate. But how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your Analytics server and then export the public key from the Keytore with the following command. The default password is `wso2carbon`

```
keytool -export -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file <public key name>.pem
```

Then in your MI server, import the public key that you extracted to the client-trustore.

```
keytool -import -alias analyticskey -file <public key name>.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
```

Comment: when importing it shows:`Valid from: Wed Oct 23 13:00:43 IST 2019 until: Tue Jan 25 13:00:43 IST 2022`. So, I guess the analytics server certificate has to be renewed. How would I do that? Or is this to be done on the WSO2 side?

Comment: @viggnah You can refer to this document. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/setup/security/creating_keystores/ Or just copy the EI key stores to the Analytics server. Make sure the password is updated properly.

Comment: Copied the EI key store to the analytics folder and it worked!